# iOS – Run/Debug/Install builds over Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, wifi

We have iPad and iPhone devices, but short of wires. Is there any way that we can install/debug the builds over Wi-Fi in iOS?

I know the way in Android, but not of iOS.

Comment: it's imposible new version of xcode. This feature is depreceated after xcode 4.3.

Comment: Right - just use testFlightApp.com  (now owned by Apple!)

Comment: I am so surprised that more developers have not clamored for this.  But I guess we sit on our arse and don't need to care whether a cable is plugged in to our iDevice or not.

Comment: Now it's possible with Xcode 9 [look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44383502/5546312)

Answer (score 170, accepted):

**Now by using Xcode 9 and iOS 11 it is possible to run apps by using Wi-Fi**.

Connect the iPhone via USB, go into the device window (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd>), select your phone, and check the `connect via network` box.

[More thorough instructions with screenshots here](https://medium.com/@santoshbotre01/wireless-debugging-ios-run-debug-install-builds-over-wifi-a48fc49ac3a7)

---

Pre-Xcode 9 answer:

Over Wi-Fi installing and debugging of applications is not possible in iOS.

But there are some websites where you can upload your builds and then download on device and test it.

Comment: I Think there was the provision for this in xcode 4.2

Comment: 2 yrs pass n still no...
I wish they can add it, especially for my 12" macbook which doesnt have usb port...

Comment: @indrajeet you can update your answer because of xcode 9

Comment: nice, to build wireless, first I need connect via wire *facepalm

Answer (score 21):

(Before you read make sure your running IOS 11 and Xcode 9!) Connect your device (Via USB), once you do go on 'Add Additional Simulators' (See image 2 at the bottom), and tick 'connect via network' (See Image One). Once XCode proccesses this, disconnect the device (via USB) and it should now appear with a globe next to it (See image 2)! Also make sure the device and computer are on the same network!

Image 1
[image]

Image 2
[image]

Comment: I don't see that option. Is this only possible on an iOS 11 device? I'm currently installing one, so I'll guess I'll find out soon enough!

Comment: Yea, requires the IOS 11 Update

Comment: You might want to include that in your answer!

Answer (score 8):

**Simple Solution:  http://diawi.com**

**Upto Xcode 8 & iOS 10 :** Through wifi its not possible.

You just upload your `".ipa"` file to this website http://diawi.com & get sort link for that. After that install build by requesting that link in iphone browser.

---

**From Xcode 9+ & iOS 11+ :** Its possible install debug build through wifi.

1. Open your project on Xcode
2. Connect your ios device with USB cable.
3. In xcode menu open **Window -> Devices and Simulators** or press `(Cmd-Shift-2)`. You should see your device as connected devices.
4. Select your device and enable check box **“Connect via network”**.
5. Now you can see a **network icon** next to your phone name. This icon confirms that you can able to run build in wifi.
6. Now run your build through wifi to install build in your ios devices.

Answer (score 8):

> Make sure you have at least Xcode 9 or later and a device with iOS 11 or later

1- Open your project on Xcode

2- Plugged in your iPhone with USB cable.

3- Open Window > Devices and Simulators
[image]
You should see your device as connected devices

4- Select Devices from the top, Select your device from left and Check the “Connect via network” box
[image]

5- Now if Xcode can connect to your device via network, you should see a network icon after your phone name

[image]

6- Unplug your USB cord

7- Go back to Xcode and Hit the Run button

[image]

Comment: It is not working, when i removed usb cable from laptop and tried to run, it is showing error as iphone not connected.

Answer (score 7):

Using Xcode 9 you can debug over wifi(same network).

Comment: Plug in your device, open Xcode, select Window > Devices and Simulators, select the device in the menu, and check "Connect via Network". Once it's connected, a globe-like icon should appear next to the device in the menu.

Comment: The question is about HOW to do the wireless connection.

Answer (score 5):

To activate a `Wireless Debugging` for iOS device to `Run`|`Debug`|`Install` your builds over Wi-Fi, you need to take six steps:

1. Connect a device via USB cable to the Mac with macOS 10.12.4+ and Xcode 9+ installed.
2. Launch Xcode.
3. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> or go to <kbd>Window</kbd>-<kbd>Devices and Simulators</kbd> menu.
4. In the `Devices` tab select the devices from the `Connected` section.
5. Select the `Connect via network` checkbox (and ***wait for a few minutes*** when it's finished).
6. Disconnect USB cable.

[image]

This **Network** icon in the left panel means – `Wireless Debugging is OK`.

[image]

> On iPhone go to `General`–`Device Management`–`Application to trust` and press <kbd>TRUST</kbd>.
>
> Now you can `Run` | `Debug` | `Install` your builds over Wi-Fi.

Answer (score 5):

To do this, connect your iOS device to your Mac using the appropriate USB cable, and select the Window tab in the menu bar, open the Devices and Simulators window by selecting Devices and Simulators from the Window dropdown or `Cmd` + `Shift` + `2`.

Ensure that your device is selected in the list farthest to the left in the Devices and Simulators window. Check the Connect via network box.

[image]

If your device is on the same network as your Mac, you’ll see a globe appear next to your device’s name within a few moments. This indicates that your device is wirelessly connected.

You can now disconnect the USB cable connecting your device to your Mac, and build and run your app wirelessly.

Answer (score 4):

For deployment/CI I have tried and highly recommend [BuddyBuild](https://buddybuild.com/) solution, here is some of the many features it has:

1. Excellent user help (chat/email) system and online service.
2. Supports [webhooks](http://docs.buddybuild.com/docs/setting-up-a-webhook) so that a build is started whenever you push to your App repository. (All Git source control repos supported)
3. You can arrange system to auto send your builds to a preset list of testers/users whenever builds are ready.
4. You can [Auto] integrate their SDK to allow user feedback and crash reports.
5. It auto checks your app for compatibility with latest Xcode versions.

Answer (score 2):

Please check out this tutorial,
http://honzadvorsky.com/articles/2015-10-21-17-40-xcode_server_tutorials_4_certificates__provisioning_profiles/

here you can find a way for "App Installation over Wi-Fi"

I have not get a chance to implement it yet, but may be will try it out asap. meanwhile if someone is free then can try and post their view here so others can get help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Requirements: iOS 11 and XCode 9, iOS device and computer on same wifi network.
Connect your device with USB Cable, launch Xcode, then on Xcode menu, choose: Window->Devices and Simulators. Choose device and check "Connect via network". Now you can disconnect USB and develop on device using wifi.
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K9rZN.png)

Answer (score 1):

" http://diawi.com "

this provides you build link of your project.
Whereas with wifi its not at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

Wireless debug requires Xcode 9 or later and iOS 11 or later. Check [this link](https://medium.com/@sourleangchhean/how-to-do-wireless-debug-on-xcode-9-and-ios-11-c12a50f256c3). Here are detail steps to connect device for wireless debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Connect the iOS device via USB. Go into the device window `(Cmd-Shift-2)`, Select your device and check `[x]` connect via network. Remove USB cable and IMPORTANT: Connect your device via Personal Hotspot.

Comment: This does not answer the question, as the original poster clearly states they are short of wires.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Amr I have found buddybuild as Jenkins+Hockey in one. Extremely useful and so far it seems good product.

With buddybuild you dont need to ask anyones UDID of their iOS device. Also I use it for test automation, where they give you freedom to spin whatever you want as long as you know how to set it up in their postbuild and prebuild scripts

Answer (score 0):

To add to the above answers, for me the Mac and the iPhone should be connected to the SAME wifi network. Otherwise it will not recognise each other.

Answer (score -3):

Over `Wifi` app installation is possible after we generate an `IPA` .

1. Create a `plist` file with `bundle identifier`
   (See apple documentation for steps )
2. Create a HTML file 
   (give the source of `IPA` (link tag) and `bundle identifier / Provisioning profile`)