# is there any way to distribute ios applications outside app store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-distribution

Is there any way to distribute ios applications through my own website, **not using app store?**
I mean is there any way that enables end users to download the .ipa file from my website with their browser application and install it directly on their iOS devices?
I have looked around in the web and googled it, but it doesn't seem to be any option for it out there, I just want to make sure of it.

Thank You

Comment: Enterprise apps might help you, but that's specific to an origanization

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS App deployment without AppStore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301361/ios-app-deployment-without-appstore)

Comment: You may distribute it via builds.io or such services.

Comment: I think this answer may fit here too: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35031940/1356559

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are several possibilities, which probably won't match your needs:

1. Since last month it's possible to test apps on a device without the need of a paid membership.
2. There's a possibility to deploy an app through a service like TestFlight, but this needs either a profile installed on the device (like HockeyApp) or always new build since the old ones expire after 30 days.
3. You could deploy an app with the [Enterprise Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/)

The easy way you describe is not possible.

Comment: Fabio, how do you test on a device without a paid membership? I could not find any info

Comment: @IanBell As far as I know you can just plug it in, register it via the Devices windows and click Run.

Comment: Option 1, 2  not possible and unreliable. Option 3 please explain in 2018

Answer (score 15):

Apart from the options mentioned above there are 2 more methods.

**Method 1:**

You could ask the user to open a webpage in safari browser with the following link in it.

href="itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=url of the manifest file"

The app is installed as soon as the user clicks the link.

**Method 2:**

You can also leverage iOS mdm solutions like [Hexnode MDM](http://mdm-demo.hexnode.com/app_management/#/) though its bit of an overkill.

[here is a link on how to distribute app without app store](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-application-management/app-distribution/)

Comment: Hi, would you please explain more about method 1, as in how's the content of the manifest file, etc. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @Zennichimaro , here is the link https://github.com/nifcblm/AHPP-iOS-App/wiki/How-to-distribute-enterprise-iOS-App

Comment: @Zennichimaro I just found the docs for Method 1: https://help.apple.com/deployment/ios/#/apda0e3426d7

Comment: The page linked by @MichaelOzeryansky is called "Distribute in-house apps wirelessly".  If you go up a few sections to "Create in-house apps", it says you need to subscribe to the Enterprise Programme (which is even more expensive than subscribing to App Store distribution).

Comment: Does Method 1 work for non-enterprise accounts, i.e., regular $99 dev accounts?

Answer (score 10):

**UPDATE:**

BuddyBuild service will stop on 1-3-2018, the other alternative I know is https://www.diawi.com

**Old ANSWER:**

Try [BuddyBuild](https://dashboard.buddybuild.com) , after making a build you can take link to IPA file and distribute it as shown.

[image]

Comment: Is the enterprise programm needed?

Answer (score 5):

The options include:

1. App Store (free or paid)
2. Enterprise Distribution (must be within an organization)
3. Open source distribution

It does not sound like any of these will meet your requirements, so no.

Further explanation:
Just to be clear, the limitation is not in distributing your .ipa file, it is the ability for users to install it on their phone. iOS requires an app be signed by Apple (from the App Store), from an Enterprise certificate, or from a developer certificate when a valid provisioning profile includes the target device.

Comment: what do you mean about open source distribution?                                             About your further explanation: do you mean if I can sign the app and create .ipa file then I could upload it to my website and people can download and install it without any problem?

Comment: Post the source code to a repository, such as GitHub and people can download and build the app. As a developer, yes you can add devices to your provisioning files and publish the .ipa for installation on your website. This will only work for the devices you include in the provisioning file, and those are limited.

Comment: You could publish an unsigned .ipa and then let the end users sign it with their dev certificates, no need to distribute the source... You could even create a Mac app (installer) to automatize the process.

Answer (score 4):

Basically there are three ways

- **App store**

With this method anyone with an iPhone can have access to the application. You can distribute an unlimited number of applications like this. Apple gets a 30% cut. Of course, Apple must approve your application.

- **Ad hoc**

You can distribute applications using ad hoc without going through the app store, but you are limited to a maximum of 100 devices. With this method you can distribute your application from a web site, email, etc.

- **Enterprise**

The method is for internal distribution in companies with more than 500 employees. Apple does not provide any more public detail that I could find on this method.

It doesn't sound like any of these methods meet your criteria unless you have fewer than 100 customers and don't plan to exceed that number. It sounds like from the question your customers are not internal to your company.

I would advise contacting Apple. They might be able to arrange some kind of custom distribution deal.

Comment: Apps distributed via Ad Hoc expire. Also the device must be added to the provisioning profile.

Comment: In Ad-Hoc the maximum is 100 devices per device type. You can now have 100 iPhones, 100 iPod Touch, 100 iPads and 100 Watches.

Comment: @zaph: In all non-app store scenarios the profiles expire. In Ad-Hoc, in Enterprise and also using Testflight (which is 30 days only from submission day).

Comment: @Kerni Enterprise expires once a year and the solution there is to update the license prior to expiration and push a new build.

Comment: Should I be able to test In App Subscriptions (in production environment) using the Ad-hoc or Enterprise mode. I am seeking real testing here, with user charged and real time. It is ok for just one device(my own) or user to be able to be tested?

Comment: With the Ad-hoc distribution, does the app expire?

Comment: What if your app is free? Does Apple get a %30 cut of nothing?

Comment: You can also build directly to a wired device. That, of course, requires the device to be physically connected at some point.

Answer (score 3):

You if don't want to upload your files to the already mentioned web services, you can host your IPA in your own computer and distribute over the internet using ngrok and the approach given by **jithin**.

I've created a server that does exactly that and also is protected by password. You can check it out here:

https://github.com/Edudjr/IPAServer

Comment: Does this still require getting the UDID of install devices?

Comment: Apparently the device still needs to be included in your provisioning. If you use automatic manage signing, you just need to run via cable once and then you are good to install using the server later on

Answer (score 2):

To send build to testers or client I am generally using [installonair.com](https://installonair.com) which allows to upload IPA file and generate short URL which we can provide to other users and they can download and install easily from that link.

There are other options as well like Apple Testflight, hockeyapp but I found installonair.com is the quick one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have and Enterprise membership you can do this, but it really isn't what they want you to do on a large scale.

Take a look at this question: [Deploying an iOS Application Using Apple Enterprise Developer Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7261255/deploying-an-ios-application-using-apple-enterprise-developer-program)

Answer (score 1):

You can use enterprise distribution services like [BuildCannon](https://buildcannon.io), but you still need an apple enterprise account. I use a custom solution, but it's a pain to maintain.