# Is it possible to publish an iPhone App without having an iPhone?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store

I am working on a simple iPhone app for a not-for-profit organization that I do some work for.  I've done extensive testing on the various emulators, and I think that the app is ready to go.  I was reading about the process to get an app on the App Store and part of the process seems to indicate that I need to register an iOS device in Xcode as part of the process.  I do not own an iPhone, and my only iOS device is an iPad Air 2.  This is not a universal app.

Is it even possible for me to put the app on the App Store?  I'm just checking because I want to be certain that I can accomplish my goal, before shelling out the $99 for a developer membership.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You need purchase Apple Developer Account and it is enough.

But it is better to test on real device before release, because sometimes you can get some errors on device only.

Comment: Thanks.  I do have people in the group that have tested it for me, and have found no issues.  Unfortunately, nobody is nearby that can loan me a device.  I'm in the US, and most of the people for whom I'm writing the app are in Canada and a few overseas.

Answer (score 2):

You can publish app without having iPhone But You need to Developer membership for publish this ... 
Read for more information [How To Submit an iOS App to the App Store](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-submit-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store--mobile-16812)

Answer (score 1):

You can publish your app without any devices but you need to make sure that you have Apple Developer Account activated. You will have to make certificate and provisioning profiles for AppStore to submit the app or you can also let Xcode handle them for you.

I would like to recommend you to test the app on real device before submitting it. You can test it on iPad as well, only there will be problem of resolution, but the app will work.

Answer (score 1):

yes its possible as #Jogendra is right you need to buy apple developer account for it then later on you can also update your app too.

Comment: Thanks for support.. :)

Answer (score -2):

You need to have a device to sign the app. Unsigned apps are nearly impossible to install.

ref: [Is it possible to generate .ipa file for iOS without "Apple Developer account" and without an Apple Device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63247510/is-it-possible-to-generate-ipa-file-for-ios-without-apple-developer-account-a)

May have a look here:
[is there any way to distribute ios applications outside app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383881/is-there-any-way-to-distribute-ios-applications-outside-app-store)

Any iOS device will be OK. You can probably find a very low cost second hand device.
It would not be very serious to distribute app without testing on at least one real device.

Comment: Sorry but this is wrong. You do not need a device to send an app to the App Store. The other question you link does not say that you need a device either.