# Does a service exist to publish my cordova app to IOS?

Tags: ios, cordova

(I've tried google but couldn't find a direct answer.)

I've created an app, mostly as a joke and published it to Android without much effort. Now my friends with iPhones want to try it too, but I don't own any Apple devices nor do I have an apple account.

Buying a macbook and an iPhone just to publish a joke seems a bit much, but I'd be willing to pay a few dollars to have it published to IOS.

Does such a service exist?

Answer (score 1):

As MStoner told you, look at build.phonegap.com

If you can get the .IPA from build.phonegap.com (if not use the MAC of a friend), once getting the file you can use https://www.diawi.com to deploy the app on your friend's phone.

Interesting links about your question :

[Is it possible to publish an iPhone App without having an iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32449604/is-it-possible-to-publish-an-iphone-app-without-having-an-iphone)

[Is it possible to make a PhoneGap app for iOS without Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887759/is-it-possible-to-make-a-phonegap-app-for-ios-without-mac)

https://nickalchemist.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/installing-iphone-apps-without-a-mac-using-apple-developer-account-and-phonegap-build-3/

Comment: These are all good references and I may end up using them. And yet I still don't know if a service that publishes an app for me exists. Do you know the answer to the original question?