# Is it possible to generate .ipa file for iOS without "Apple Developer account" and without an Apple Device?

Tags: xcode, flutter

I'm trying to run the command below but it says *"Failed to create provisioning profile. There are no devices registered in your account on the developer website. Plug in and select a device to have Xcode register it."*

```
flutter build ios
```

Does anyone knows if is possible to build the iOS files without a Apple Device registered?

*I've setted up a VirtualBox with [macOS Catalina 10.15.3] + [xCode] + [Android Studio] + [Flutter] in Windows

Comment: It's not possible

Comment: you need apple id which must be connected to xcode....to build app

Comment: This video shows how to build unsigned IPA. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SXRimW23AjI) I did the test and it works even if we don't have an Apple device connected. But it's very dificult to install an unsigned IPA on iPhone.

Answer (score 9):

It's possible to create an unsigned iOS .ipa without code signing.

1. Run the Flutter app first to an iOS simulator to generate iOS build on **/build/ios**.
2. Create a folder anywhere you like with
   the name `Payload` - note that this is case sensitive.
3. Navigate
   to **/build/ios/iphonesimulator** and copy Runner.app to the
   `Payload` folder you've created.
4. Compress the `Payload` folder with
   default .zip format
5. Rename **Payload.zip** to **Payload.ipa**

Installing the .ipa file to an iOS device is a different topic, however.

Comment: please do you have any tutorial on how to install the .ipa or any article that you can refer me to?

Comment: you know how can i install my app after this steps? please answer me

Comment: @AminRezaew You can use AltStore

Comment: @UsamaSaleem but AltStore have limit and after 7 days needed to use it again

Comment: @AminRezaew yeah so you need to pay apple 100$/yr for a dev account for more than that

Comment: @UsamaSaleem ok thanks, if you found another way to install without pay and AltStore please tell me

Comment: @AminRezaew There is no way to go around the limits set by apple

Comment: It is not downloading in iPhone.

Comment: Thank you so much !

To simply install the ipa download this https://sideloadly.io/ plug in your iDevice, log in and start the installation. When it's Done go to Settings > General > VPN & Device Management > Your mail > Trust