# Distributing App without Apple Developer

Tags: iphone

Is there any way to distribute an app from Xcode without enrolling in the Apple Developer Program? I don't necessarily want to put it on the App Store. I have downloaded apps of the internet before and was wondering if there is a way to do that just so I can give it to my friends and family.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there any way to distribute ios applications outside app store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383881/is-there-any-way-to-distribute-ios-applications-outside-app-store)

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately, Apple never allow anyone to launch app except iTunes Store