# Apple : Private App without an enterprise developer program

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, app-distribution

Having an Apple developer program, but not an enterprise program, how can I develope a private app (for ex. <100 devices)?
Choosing to use TestFlight for download the app to N. devices, which are the limits in this case (app expiry, certificate expiry, renenew the app every months/years)?
It’s correct to use TestFlight for this propose?

Comment: Apps deployed with TestFlight will expire after 90 days. This means you must renew your app about every 3 months.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31383881/is-there-any-way-to-distribute-ios-applications-outside-app-store for other options.