# Is it possible to debug application wireless or without connecting USB cable in XCODE?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, debugging, usb

how to connect device in xcode without cable. it is tedious to connect the cable and my USB is lil bit loose, so it disconnects from PC.

Comment: This is possible now with XCode 9.x and iOS 11.x, check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-to-do-wireless-debug-on-xcode-9-and-ios-11/44383502#44383502)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS- Run/Debug/Install builds over WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23827168/ios-run-debug-install-builds-over-wifi)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Over wifi installing and debugging of applications is not possible in ios.

But there are some websites where you can upload your builds and then download on device and test it.

WiFi debugging has never been supported in any public releases of Xcode yet.

- There are third party hacks that may or may not work:
  https://github.com/Shopify/superdb
- There also reports that this works with some workarounds:
  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7857052/361247

But officially, this isn't supported.

Comment: @IndrajitChavda It will be now possible with Xcode 9.

Comment: it is possible now https://medium.com/swiftist/wireless-debugging-xcode-b6e98e26e022

Answer (score 11):

It will be now possible with the latest update of Xcode 9.

> **Cut the Cord**
>
> Choose any of your iOS or tvOS devices on the local
> network to install, run, and debug your apps – without a USB cord
> plugged into your Mac. Simply click the ‘Connect via Network’ checkbox
> the first time you use a new iOS device, and that device will be
> available over the network from that point forward. Wireless
> development also works in other apps, including Instruments,
> Accessibility Inspector, Quicktime Player, and Console.

Check [this](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) for the latest updates.

Answer (score 8):

**Wireless debugging is possible now with XCode 9.x and iOS 11.x**. Check [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-to-do-wireless-debug-on-xcode-9-and-ios-11/44383502#44383502) for steps to connect device for wireless debugging.

Answer (score 4):

This is now officially supported as a built-in feature in Xcode 9.

[How do you perform wireless debugging in Xcode 9 with iOS 11, Apple TV 4K, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382841/how-do-you-perform-wireless-debugging-in-xcode-9-with-ios-11-apple-tv-4k-etc)

Comment: I am excited for this feature too. I wonder how many devices can be networked up at once.